# Output message is not getting displayed when @ModelAttribute is used with @ControllerAdvice in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute, controller-advice

I am trying to add ModelAttribute value to different pages within the same application with the help of ControllerAdvice but output message is not getting displayed on the jsp pages.

ServicesController.java

```
package com.test;     
@Controller
public class ServicesController {
@RequestMapping("/serviceUser") 
public String dis() {
return "input";
}
}
```

ProductsController.java

```
package com.test;     
@Controller
public class ProductsController {
@RequestMapping("/products")
public ModelAndView display()
{
ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("output");
return m;
}
}
```

GlobalAdviceHandler.java

```
package com.test;     
@ControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalAdviceHandler {
@ModelAttribute 
public void show(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("msg", "hello world");
}
}
```

input.jsp

```
<body>
<p>Services </p>
${msg}
</body>
```

output.jsp

```
   <body>
   <p>Products </p>
    ${msg}
    </body>
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You need to add `@ControllerAdvice` in your controller after `@Controller`, as well.

Comment: Added @ControllerAdvice in both ServicesController and  ProductsController classes after Controller but still output is not coming

Comment: @Harry You Can checkout this [Link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/controller-advice-with-model-attribute.html)

Comment: It's working now message is getting displayed for jsp pages. Thank you

Comment: If I run the program with ControllerAdvice written after Controller in Service and Products classes(as advised by @Amitkumar) it run fine and if I only write Controller then also it run fine. What is the use of writing ControllerAdvice and Controller together in one class?